# How to add user reviews and ratings scores to my site?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, rating-system

I am building an online store in ASP.NET Web Forms 4.0 and i would like to add a feature to it. I would like to add some user reviews(commentaries) to my products and some ratings scores.

- Can someone help me on how should i implement these things ?
- Is    there on the internet any downlodable content(I didn't find
  any) ?
- **Can you provide me some useful links on how should I implement
  this ?**
- Any advice or tips and tricks ?
- Ratings scores  require javascript ?

Comment: Your question violates  almost every rule in the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone help me on how should i implement these things ?

You can use jQuery, ASP.NET, SQL Databases mixed up with each other to create this system.

You will require HTML to create the stars, and then jQuery to handle the events (click dblclick etc) and sent the Ajax requests to the server.

ASP.NET would handle them all and save them or what so ever.

SQL Database would be required to save the data if required. This is the basic of this system to save and get the ratings by the user. You can use third-party plugins too. But creating one of your own would be the best option.

> Is there on the internet any downlodable content(I didn't find any) ?

Internet is used by downloading Stuff, you even downloaded this page on to your browser. You didn't find any, or you didn't bother searching for it thoroughly? I bet you would have found good stuff.

> Can you provide me some useful links on how should I implement this ?

I think this is the question that you are wrapping inside other text.

Here is a good tutorial from Mike Brind, that you might love too. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/114/jQuery-Star-Rating-with-ASP.NET-MVC

He is using ASP.NET MVC to let the user post the rating on his system. Posting a part of his code won't be good here. You need to use it all. Go there and learn it you will understand, he's a good teacher. Trust me.

> Any advice or tips and tricks ?

Keep working out! You'll figure out the tricks and tips as you move. Until then, all that I can tell you is to learn the API and keep using and learning it through proper usage of them in your applications.

> Ratings scores require javascript ?

Only if you want to do some dynamic stuff. For example if you want to store the rating synchronously like ajax request etc. If you want to change the content or the color of the rating stars etc. Then you require JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, i needed some advice to get some ideas.

Comment: You can have a look at the answer now :) I have answered all of your questions, and at the same time I have provided a link for the example code...

Comment: okay, now i know what to search on the internet. thanks a lot.

Comment: do upvote if it helps you. if it answers your post then mark it as answer as thanks :-)